# How do I remove spaces, dashes, and periods with replace in JavaScript in a concise way?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Is there a way to do the below in a more efficient (cleaner) manner?

```
function phoneFormat(number){
      var noSpace = number.split(" ").join("");
      var noSpace = noSpace.replace(/-/g, "");
      return noSpace.replace(/./g, "");
    }
```

After changing this number I want to reformat it to (ddd) ddd-dddd. I was thinking of using split and push to do this, but is there a smarter way?

Comment: How sure are you, that these numbers are always 12 digits long? I know that for our company our central call is 1 digit shorter than my direct call. Also the country code might differ from 1 digit up to 6, with either 2 leading 0 or the +-sign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a *character class* with your regular expression:

```
return number.replace(/[- .]/g, "");
```

That said "replace all `-`, space, and `.` characters in the string with a blank string." The `[]` denote the class, which means "any of these characters." Note that I put the `-` at the beginning of it; if it's not at the beginning or end, you have to escape it with a backslash because otherwise it introduces a *range* of characters in the class (e.g., `A-Z` is all the upper case English letters). But when it's the first thing (just after the `[`) or the last thing (just before the `]`), it's not special. Also note that while `.` is usually special in regular expressions (meaning "any character here"), it isn't special inside a character class.

---

Re your comment:

> do you know if there's a smart way to reformatting it to (ddd) ddd-ddd?

You said `(ddd) ddd-dddd` in your question, so I'll assume there are four at the end rather than three (e.g., you're in the U.S., Canada, or many other parts of the Americas):

If, say, `x` has `"1234567890"`, then `x.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/, '($1) $2-$3')` will return `"(123) 456-7890"`. The `(...)` are *capture groups*, and the `$1` and such in the replacement string are where to put the captured text.

So:

```
return number.replace(/[- .]/g, "").replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/, '($1) $2-$3');
```

The `\d` means "digit" (0-9), and the `{3}` means "exactly three of the thing before," so `\d{3}` means "three digits" (and of course, `\d{4}` means "exactly four digits"). The `^` and `$` "assert" the beginning and the end of the input.

---

I should note, though, that validating and reformatting phone numbers tends to be problematic. For instance, by doing the above, you're making it impossible for someone to use international phone numbers, or phone numbers with extensions (e.g., (408) 555-1212 ext 1234), etc.

Comment: @TJ awesome thanks! do you know if there's a smart way to reformatting it to (ddd) ddd-ddd?

Comment: Just as a little side note: you can als put the minus in the end of the character class, to avoid its range-meaning

Comment: @jlei: If, say, `x` has `"123456789"`, then `x.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})$/, '($1) $2-$3')` will convert it into `"(123) 456-789"`. The `(...)` are *capture groups*, and the `$1` and such in the replacement string are where to put the captured text.

Comment: @Nitin9791: True. The OP didn't say he wanted to replace all whitespace. He asked how to do "this" more efficiently, and showed code replacing spaces. My guess is he's processing a user input and it won't have tabs or newlines, but it's trivial to tweak the above if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is more useful to exclude anything that is not a digit and then perform the final formatting with the digit-only string:

```
function phoneFormat(input) {
    return input.replace(/\D/g, '')
                .replace(/(...)(...)(....)/, '($1) $2-$3');
}

console.log(phoneFormat('123/45.67.890'));
```

Outputs:

> (123) 456-7890

The `\D` must be capital and matches anything that is not a digit.

The dot in the second regular expression matches any character, but at that point we already know they are all digits. With three capture groups we can then use back-references to them to do the final formatting.

The downside of the above function is that it returns digits only, even if the input does not represent a phone number. If that is an issue then you can go for this variant:

```
function phoneFormat(input) {
    var digits = input.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (digits.length !== 10) return input; // not valid: return original
    return digits.replace(/(...)(...)(....)/, '($1) $2-$3');
}
```

This will only return a formatted string if there are exactly 10 digits in the original input.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
function phoneFormat(number){
return number.replace(/-|\.|\s/g,'').replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})/g,'($1) $2-$3');
}
```